# CodeIgniter - Multiple view with session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, frameworks

I am unsure why I am getting this error when i use nested view in my controller.

**Error Message :**

> **An Error Was Encountered**
>
> Unable to load the requested file: .php

this is my controller for my administrator page which load a view with session.

**Controller :**

```
//...
function index()
 {
   if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
   {
     $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
     $data_user['username'] = $session_data['username'];

     $data['main'] = $this->load->view('admin/dashboard', $data_user);
     $this->load->view('template', $data);
   }
   else
   {
     //If no session, redirect to login page
     redirect('login', 'refresh');
   }
 ...//
```

i think there's maybe something wrong when i load up **template.php** with **dashboard.php** inside *admin* folder which using session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to load in view file another view like

```
if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
   {
     $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
     $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];

     $data['main'] = 'admin/dashboard';
     $this->load->view('template', $data);
   }
```

in your views/template.php

```
$this->load->view($main);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load multiple views by

```
$this->load->view('admin/dashboard', $data_user);
$this->load->view('template', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this as follows in your controller

```
<?php
function index()
 {
   if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
     $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
     $data_user['username'] = $session_data['username'];

     $data['main'] = 'admin/dashboard'; 
     $data['view_data']=$data_user['username'];
     $this->load->view('template', $data);
   }
   else
   {
     //If no session, redirect to login page
     redirect('login', 'refresh');
   }
 ...//
?>
```

and in template

```
<?php 
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view($main,$view_data);
$this->load->view('footer');
?>
```